# Link to registration page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

There is

`wp_login_url`, `wp_logout_url`, but what what about registration url?

Is there standard way to get link to registration? I need to display a link to registration page with further redirect to previous page.

PS I am using **my theme login**.

Comment: Have updated the answer to match your original question ;)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The following will return the registration url:

```
<?php

    echo site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register');

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

To get the registration url with a redirect to the current page use:

```
<?php

    echo site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register&redirect_to=' . get_permalink());

?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the redirect_to parameter: esc_url_raw(get_permalink())

Comment: Why do you need to escape get_permalink?

Comment: Oh Wordpress! So elegant... Thanks for the reply John.

Comment: just what I was looking for to test registration from the browser

Answer (score 20):

Since 3.6, there is now a func:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_registration_url

```
<?php echo wp_registration_url(); ?>
```

You can override it with the `register_url` filter.

```
add_filter( 'register_url', 'custom_register_url' );
function custom_register_url( $register_url )
{
    $register_url = get_permalink( $register_page_id );
    return $register_url;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone picking it up use [wp_register()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register).

It automatically determines if you're logged in and supplies either a link to the admin section of the site, or a link to the register form.

It also respects the settings in Settings -> General -> Membership (Anyone Can Register?)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are asking for default Word Press registration page. That would be `www.domainname.com/wp-signup.php`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo wp_registration_url(); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_registration_url

Answer (score 1):

2 points here

1. Make sure you have turn on the "Anyone can register" in the setting page
2. if you host in a subfolder, make sure you include

Without subfolder:

```
<a href="/wp-login.php?action=register">Register</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_registration_url(); ?>">Register</a>
```

With subfolder

```
<a href="shop/wp-login.php?action=register">Register</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of hosting your wordpress site in a subfolder (e.g.: `mysite.com/myblog`) you also need to include your site's url as follows:

`<?php echo get_site_url() . "/wp-login.php?action=register" ?>`

*`--> http://mysite.com/myblog/wp-login.php?action=register`*

Otherwise you will be redirected to a non-existing page

*`--> http://mysite.com/wp-login.php?action=register`*

Answer (score 0):

1st of all I'm a WP newbe.

wp_registration_url can redirect the new user back to the page he came from, buy without enforcing login on the way (I dont use auto login because i want the user to authenticate the mail).

i use instead (sample with Allow PHP in posts plugin):

```
<a href="[php]echo site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register&redirect_to=/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . get_permalink());[/php]" title="Register">Register</a>
```

hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp_registration_url() any where you want to add link to wordpress registration
to add the redirection url use apply_filters()

```
<a href="<?php wp_registration_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post_id ) ) ); ?>" >click to register</a>
```